# Ubuntu fails to boot after update

Tags: boot, grub2, busybox

A couple of months ago I've built a computer for my grandfather and (as he requested) installed Ubuntu as his OS. This worked fine until a few days ago. He called me and said his computer isn't working. After some questions I had some specifics:

- turning the computer on, the screen flashes and then stays black
- he updated Ubuntu as always when the pop-up from the software center came; the next day it didn't boot anymore
- he thinks he remembers reading something about Ubuntu 15.10 before pressing update (I installed Ubuntu 14.04 originally)

With this information my search began. I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash), which got us to a busy box. We couldn't proceed with the steps in the answer though because `/boot` wasn't found. The other answer didn't work either.

Later on I found [this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1561735&p=9786657#post9786657) which we could follow until `insmod /boot/grub/linux.mod`, which failed because the file doesn't exist.

I don't really know what to do anymore. I don't have physical access to the computer because my grandparents live about 500km away from me. I don't think my grandfather could create a Live-CD / Live-USB. At least it would be a very long phone call. Is there any hope to solve this without me driving there for a weekend and doing a fresh install of Ubuntu?

I'll attach some pictures from various command outputs he sent me over the last couple of days. Maybe they are helpful for some of you, maybe not.

[image: failing to mount some directories and not requesting /sbin/init]

[image: some outputs from grub while following along the instructions from the mentioned threads]

Comment: In my case, on 14.04 64bit, it should be `insmod /boot/grub/i386-pc/linux.mod`, because that's where the linux.mod file is. ...given the variables, I think you should get ready for a weekend drive.

Comment: Did you specify any boot partition manually?

Comment: @mikewhatever could it be that the ```linux.mod``` is in ```/boot/grub/x86_64-efi```?     

@WeareBorg when I installed Ubuntu originally I didn't. In the last couple of days I probably did. I'm not to sure what all the commands I used (see the sources above) did (or were supposed to do). I just figured it couldn't get worse anyway and went ahead to blindly try them.